# Unable to extract object values in Typescript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to convert a JavaScript web form to Typescript, and have been unable to work out how to deal with the following (which works in JavaScript):

```
let fieldValues = JSON.parse(cookieData);

let keys = Object.keys(fieldValues);

let values = Object.values(fieldValues);
```

Visual Studio tells me:

> Error TS2339  Property 'values' does not exist on type
>   'ObjectConstructor'.

What can I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Object.values(..)` is not stabilized, so it is unsupported in many browsers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Use `map` instead:

```
let values = Object.keys(fieldValues).map(key => fieldValues[key]);
```

> If you really want to use this function you need to add the `"es2017.object"` lib on your `tsconfig.json`. Make sure you are using a polyfill or if your final platform support this feature.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about this. I was not aware that Object.values was not stabilised.

Comment: I'm glad to help you :)

Comment: The specification is stable, frozen, committed (stage 4); it's just not implemented everywhere yet, and of course probably never will be on IE et al.  See https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries .

Answer (score 20):

If you need the value of a specific key you can access it using the following method :

```
Object(nameofobj)["nameofthekey"]
```

Answer (score 9):

If `Object.values` is not supported ([which today is often the case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility)), you can just [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over your `keys`:

```js
let cookieData = '{"key":"value"}'

let fieldValues = JSON.parse(cookieData)

let keys = Object.keys(fieldValues)

let values = keys.map(k => fieldValues[k])

console.log(keys) //=> ['key']
console.log(values) //=> ['value']
```

Answer (score 4):

Just as an alternative. You also could use [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

```
let obj = {...};
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(key => {
    let value = obj[key];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're googling this and want to know how to do this for types, you can use the `(typeof x)[keyof typeof x]` pattern:

```
const VARIANTS_BY_ID = {
  100: 'diagonal',
  120: 'knight',
  125: 'king',
  200: 'disjointGroups',
  300: 'consecutive',
} as const;

// type Variants = "diagonal" | "knight" | "king" | "disjointGroups" | "consecutive"
type Variants = (typeof VARIANTS_BY_ID)[keyof typeof VARIANTS_BY_ID];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, any respose worked in my setup, so i tryed this:

```
 let formattedData = {}
 for (let index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
   eval("formattedData[indexToChar(index)] = values[index]");
 }
```

basicaly it works because js understand it, but ts dont, so if i use **eval** ts dont try to parse and dont throw error, so js read it and excecute correctely.
eval doc:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval