# Iterate over values of object yields undefined

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example:

```
type IQByName = Partial<Record<string, number>>;
const iqByName: IQByName = { Trump: 185 };

for (const iq of Object.values(iqByName)) {
  const iq2 = 2 * iq; // Object is possibly 'undefined'
  console.log(iq2);
}
```

The compiler complains that `iq` might be `undefined`. What's the proper way of modelling an object with optional keys and iterating over all defined values inside the object?

Comment: The problem is not really your model, it's the definition of `Object.values()`, which necessarily includes the possibility of returning undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround I would imagine, although it seems to work:

```
for (const iq of Object.values(iqByName)) {
  if (iq === undefined) throw new Error("IQ undefined.");
  const iq2 = 2 * iq; // Object is possibly 'undefined'
  console.log(iq2);
}
```

**Example**:

https://repl.it/repls/ConsciousCrazyTransversals

Answer (score -1):

Object.values seems to be unsupported by a lot of browsers, and may return things like undefined. You should iterate through the `Object.keys()` and gets the values for each key.

See: [Unable to extract object values in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147696/unable-to-extract-object-values-in-typescript)

What you want is:

```
type IQByName = Partial<Record<string, number>>;
const iqByName: IQByName = { Trump: 185 };

for (const iqKey of  Object.keys(iqByName)) {
    const iq2 = 2 * iqByName[iqKey];
    console.log(iq2);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9gztdxw5/